# laravel call command in blade file prints zero

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

Hello I know that the zero after a Artisan::call function is the ExitCode an it means that the command was successfull. I run the command for some MySQLI DB queries. And then I print it on the website and there is always the zero at the end. Is there a way to disable the ExitCode?

my handle() function:

```
public function handle(){
$conn = mysqli_connect("***********","***********","************","********");

if($conn->connect_errno){
    printf("Connection failed!", $conn->connect_error);
    exit();
} else {
    $result = $conn->query("select * from VoiceJoin order by VoiceJoinID desc limit 5");
}

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['UserName']."-";
}

$conn->close();}
```

And in a blade file I'm calling my command:

```
{{ Artisan::call('get:latest:voice:join') }}
```

Output: http://prntscr.com/jynoqy
And there is the zero at the end.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command on controller and pass as variable on blade,

```
$result =  str_replace_last('0', '', Artisan::call('get:latest:voice:join')) ;
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: yes helped but now when the site laoded it will echo it at the top of the page and its 
$result =  str_replace_last('0', '', \Artisan::call('get:latest:voice:join')) ; with a backslash ;D